# I am going to connect Cassandra Database with Java API

Tags: java, cassandra

```
package com.nokia.main;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

/*
 cassandra.contactpoints=localhost,127.0.0.1
 cassandra.port=9042
 cassandra.keyspace=ranga*/
public class CassandraConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverIp = "127.0.0.1";
        String keyspace = "ranga";
        CassandraConnection connection;

        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(serverIp).build();

        Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

        String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
            System.out.println(row.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

So and getting Exception Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigure

Comment: Is Cassandra running on localhost? Is native/binary transport (tcp/9042) listening on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Please provide complete exception message. Seems the (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigure .....) is incomplete message.

Comment: Possible duplicate to -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136525/com-datastax-driver-core-exceptions-invalidqueryexception-using-datastax-java-dr

Comment: Now my code is working fine and add in below mentioned dependency------------------- <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.3</version>
  </dependency>